# How to convert the time difference to hours(with 2 decimal place) in derby?

Tags: sql, database, derby

I am using timestampdiff in derby db to retrieve the time difference between 2 time: startdate, and enddate. e.g.

startdate = `2010-02-23 02:59:52.045`
enddate = `2010-02-23 03:45:39.898`

```
select {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_HOUR, startdate, enddate)} as diff
```

I would like to know how can I get the time diff in hours, e.g. 0.25, etc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_MINUTE, startdate, enddate)}/60 as diff
```

and I would call the variables startdatetime and enddatetime.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for HOURS difference use "SQL_TSI_HOUR"

```
select {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_HOUR, startdate, enddate)} as diff
```

see here: https://docs.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/33476.htm