# compare two dates to find time difference in Derby

Tags: sql, derby

I have a table with 2 columns,

```
Task_Start                  Task_End
2019-01-27 07:14:50         2019-01-28 07:25:25
```

How do I calculate the time difference (let's say in seconds) using Derby DB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468428/how-to-convert-the-time-difference-to-hourswith-2-decimal-place-in-derby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like below

```
select {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_FRAC_SECOND, Task_Start, Task_End)} as diff
```

Comment: Getting this error ` [Code: 30000, SQL State: 42X01]  Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 100.`

Comment: @ScrapCode: of course you have to add a `from your_table` clause to that

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin, I'm trying to run this from dbVisualizer tool but its not working, Do you want me to try this using `Java` ?

Comment: @ScrapCode. maybe DbVisualizer disables JDBC escapes. I can run that without problems in my JDBC based query tool [and in `ij`](https://i.imgur.com/qA1DJea.png)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, The image you shared really helped. I appreciate it.